# Manipulate with cache as with collection in Spring

Tags: java, spring, caching, concurrency, spring-cache

I looked a lot of stuff on on internet but I don't found any solution for my needs.

Here is a sample code which doesn't work but show my requirements for better understanding.

```
@Service
public class FooCachedService {

    @Autowired
    private MyDataRepository dataRepository;

    private static ConcurrentHashMap<Long, Object> cache = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public void save(Data data) {
        Data savedData = dataRepository.save(data);
        if (savedData.getId() != null) {
            cache.put(data.getRecipient(), null);
        }
    }

    public Data load(Long recipient) {
        Data result = null;

        if (!cache.containsKey(recipient)) {
            result = dataRepository.findDataByRecipient(recipient);
            if (result != null) {
                cache.remove(recipient);
                return result;
            }
        }

        while (true) {
            try {
                if (cache.containsKey(recipient)) {
                    result = dataRepository.findDataByRecipient(recipient);
                    break;
                }
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

and data object:

```
public class Data {
    private Long id;
    private Long recipient;
    private String payload;

    // getters and setters
}
```

As you can see in code above I need implement service which will be stored new data into database and into cache as well.

Whole algorithm should looks something like that:

Some userA create POST request to my controller to store data and it fire save method of my service.

Another userB logged in system send request GET to my controller which fire method load of my service. In this method is compared logged user's id which sent request with recipients' ids in map. If map contains data for this user they are fetched with repository else algorithm check every second if there are some new data for that user (this checking will be some timeout, for example 30s, and after 30s request return empty data, and user create new GET request and so on...)

Can you tell me if it possible do it with some elegant way and how? How to use cache for that or what is the best practice for that? I am new in this area so I will be grateful for any advice.

Comment: I don't see in your code where you actually put data into your cache.

Comment: And why do you remove `recepient` from the cache if `cache` did not contain the recepient anyway?

Comment: @lexicore In code I don't use real cache, I only show example how I want to use cache if it possible.

Comment: This is my point - it is hard to understand how you actually want to use a cache.

Comment: First question is which call do you actually want to cache.

Comment: @lexicore I want cache data manually, when in controller is called save method. This data are saved into database and also into cache where it will be waiting until another user call load method by controller, and this data read and delete from cache.

Comment: So you basically want to save a database call or what?

Comment: save to database and also to cache. because when another user call load method from controller, this method will be async, and will periodically checked if there is some new data. I don't want to kill database with too much requests, so because I want it check in loop just cache in database

Comment: I was thinking about solving this with Spring Cache, but now it seems to be that it won't be suitable. I understand now what you want but I don't think it's actually cache. Looks more like some pub-sub.